# a question about abstract algebra, prove that $HK\cong H\times K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of a group $G$, $HK=KH$ and $H\cap K=\{1\}$. Prove that $$HK\cong H\times K.$$

Can some one tell me how to prove this question? I have spent too much time in it, still have no idea? Can someone tell me how to prove it? I know from HK=KH,we can know HK is a subgroup, but I am still not sure how to prove it?

Comment: It is a long process as far as I remember. Where do you need help precisely? Have you made any progress?

Comment: where the subgroups normal?

Comment: the question didn't tell me which one is normal subgroup, and the question is that how to prove the function hk->(h,k) is homomorphism

Comment: I am stuck at how to prove hk->(h,k) is homomorphism, since I need to know whether hk=kh?

Comment: It is funny, because this step uses normality of both the subgroups, I think. @tiandiao123

Comment: Maybe the question has something wrong, but the question in my book really doesn't tell me whether H or K is normal subgroup

Comment: Just wondering, what book is this?

Comment: abstract algebra written by Joseph J.Rotman

Answer (score 4):

This is not true in general.  Take, for example, the dihedral group
$$D_n = \langle \rho, \tau \ | \ \rho^n = \tau^2 = 1, \ \rho\tau = \tau\rho^{-1}\rangle.$$
If $H = \langle\rho\rangle$ and $K = \langle\tau\rangle$ then $HK = D_n = KH$ and $H \cap K = 1$ but $D_n$ is not a direct product of cyclic groups.

Comment: Oh right, in the version I knew the subgroups where both normal, perhaps he was missing that.

Comment: @JorgeFernández Yes, it is indeed the case, I guess.

Comment: My opinion of the OP is not so low that I think he can't sub in $n = 4$ on his own if he chooses :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to find a bijection between the true. Here are some hints:

Prove every element in $HK$ can be written uniquely as $hk$. Prove the function $hk\mapsto (h,k)$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: I know it's bijection, but I am stuck at how to prove hk->(h,k) is a homomorphism, since I don't know whether hk=kh?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add the assumption that $H$ and $K$ are both normal subgroups. Then you can look at the commutator $[h,k]$, where $h\in H$ and $k\in K$ and show that it is in both $H$ and $K$, so it must be the identity. Then you complete the result as Jorge describes.